# Securing a web chat: how can I use Firebase JWT idToken with IBM Watson Assistant?

Tags: firebase-authentication, ibm-cloud, ibm-watson, watson-assistant

https://cloud.ibm.com/docs/watson-assistant?topic=watson-assistant-web-chat-security

I'm trying to integrate IBM Watson Assistant (web chat) with Firebase for user authentication, and I've encountered a requirement from IBM Watson Assistant in "Secure your web chat" to provide a public certificate to verify the user's identity. However, Firebase hasn't provided me with any public certificate.

My understanding is that Firebase Authentication uses JWT tokens for user authentication, and I'm unsure why IBM Watson Assistant is requesting a public certificate. Can anyone provide guidance on this?

However, when attempting enable "Secure your web chat", IBM Watson Assistant requests a public certificate. So, how do I obtain a public certificate from Firebase?

The web app requires login in advance, so the user is already logged in.

Thanks in advance. I don't speak english as native.

Here are the steps I've followed so far:

1. Configured user authentication in Firebase and obtained JWT tokens after successful login on an Angular-Ionic App.
2. Set up IBM Watson Assistant web chat and enabled "Securing your web chat"

I tried to place the first public key of multiple https://www.googleapis.com/robot/v1/metadata/x509/XXXXXXXXXXXXXXX addresses but without success.